# Power controller says 0/10vdc command signal what does that mean?

Tags: power-supply, signal

I have a power controller here and I try shorting these two prongs but it doesn't turn on and give me 12 volts. I'm new to electronic engineering so does the 10 vdc on the manual mean that I have to apply 10 volts dc to the prongs in order for the power supply to turn on?

Here's a pic [image]

For reference, the [manual is here (PDF)](http://www.pcscontrols.com/sites/default/files/ControlIR-1025%20Manual.pdf). The connectors are shown by the figure at the top of page 5.

Comment: Is that a SSR? It likely won't switch  12V DC if it's an AC  SSR.

Comment: I noticed it was AC, on the manual I can't seem to find the general output voltage for it.

Comment: Based on the extensive dialog and responses I am seeing, I don't think you are going to get this to work. It seems like you don't really know what it does, and don't want to listen to anyone's advice. This is not intended as criticism. Just an observation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the manual yes you need to supply a control signal.

See the manual, you need a variable resistor connected to the four pin connector.

(1K pot recommended, 20K permissible)

[image]

Comment: If I just need a solid 12v from the power controller is pot necessary? I just want to be able to turn it on and off with the control signal.

Comment: @ChrisEthanFox, look at the troubleshooting chart ... #1 is no controller connected.

Comment: And It is unknown how the device uses the POT, if it is in series with some other regulation resistors, just tieing it to a rail may break it.

Comment: Also, there is an AC step down transformer which is supposed to supply the power controller with 24 volts AC, I measure it with my multimeter but the multimeter gives me 31 V-AC. Could this be a potential problem?

Comment: @ChrisEthanFox,  It could be a different problem but unlikely.

Comment: This controller is connected to an RF gen. in the picture from left to right pins 1 and 2 are connected to the ballast. The other 2 pins aren't connected to anything.

Comment: This seems to be an AC power control. Like a dimmer. How are you going to get 12V out of it?

Comment: The POT will allow adjustment of the output, like a dimmer. The other sketches show two other options: You can apply 10V from `CCW` to `W` to turn it on, or 0V to turn it off; or apply 5VDC to the pin marked `5` relative to `CCW` for on, and 0V for off. There is no combination of pins that can be shorted to turn it on, only combinations that force it off.

Comment: @ChrisEthanFox if you are measuring the transformer without a load, then you will likely get a higher voltage reading. The transformer should level out to it's stated voltage at or near it's stated load.

Comment: @mkeith I just assumed it was DC 12v sorry I'm so used to seeing power supplies generally being 12 vdc

Comment: @RBerteig like I said only the first to pins on the left are connected to the rf generator so I probably won't need a pot.

Comment: @RBerteig The pins that are connected are the two on the left. Would the output voltage default to a certain voltage by just supplying a 5vdc command signal without a pot?

Comment: @ChrisEthanFox I think you are totally misunderstanding what that device does... The control pins NEED a POT.. period.